# How to pull data with most recent status update per customer

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to construct a query that would only retrieve the most recent status update per customer.
I've attached an image of how the data is currently constructed and how I would like it to be returned.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK6gc.png)

Comment: what DBMS are you using ? flavors of SQL are different. Window functions should work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Given the table name is customer_requests, the easiest solution would be:

```
select
    cr1.*
from
    customer_requests cr1
inner join customer_requests cr2 on
    cr1.customer = cr2.customer
group by
    cr1.customer,
    cr1.status,
    cr1.status_time_stamp
having
    cr1.status_time_stamp = max(cr2.status_time_stamp);
```

The solution above is doing a self join using *customer* but it is not so efficient.

A more efficient solution would be:

```
select
    cr1.*
from
    customer_requests cr1
inner join (
    select
        cr2.customer, max(cr2.status_time_stamp) as most_recent_timestamp
    from
        customer_requests cr2
    group by
        cr2.customer) vcr on
    cr1.customer = vcr.customer
    and cr1.status_time_stamp = vcr.most_recent_timestamp;
```

Now the self join is being done using an *inline table* with the alias *vcr* (representing a virtual table of customer_requests), the inline table has reduced the number of joins to be made by a significant amount, therefore increasing performance of the query.

Answer (score 0):

if you use sql server:

```
select distinct customerID,t2.status,t2.date
from table  t
cross apply 
         (select top 1 status ,date        
          from customer 
          where customerID=t.customerID   
          order by date desc) t2
```